# Can't set td width

Tags: html, css

I am working on a table 
Here is a link to my code [LINK](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeJYPP).
My question is : I want the td with `prono` class to occupy 40px width and the other td to get the rest of the width.
Hope i can get your help

Comment: Your code link shows 404 error message

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @MJM I just updated it. Thank you

Comment: You can style a particular td using id selector and use class selector to style rest of td tags

Comment: @MJM I have other same tables on the page some will need the same attributes as prono. thanks

Comment: If you have same tables you can use class selector. You can add multiple class selector to a td tag. Use !important which will give higher specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width of the TD, but there are other elements on the same column which doesn't fit in 40px width so the actual width is limited to the TD with a date.

You could have something like this to target the last TD on every row which is not a first TD at the same time:

```
table tr td:last-child:not(:first-child){
  width: 40px;
}
```

But the actual minimal size is still limited by the width of the date on the other row.